# How to ignore one or multiple packages from setpackagestoscan while creating multiple data source using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, package, datasource

[image]

I am creating two data sources for my project. One is for authentication module and another is for all other modules. While writing configuration classes i need to provide the packages to scan in both the configuration class. In authentication configuration class i am only providing the authentication package, where as on common configuration file i need to provide all other package except authentication. So i need to exclude authentication module. It is practically impossible to provide all package names to scan for entity excluding one only in an already developed and big project.

This is config class for AuthDataSourceConfiguration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
//only need to scan auth repository module here for repository managment
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.multipledatasouce.auth.repo", entityManagerFactoryRef = "authEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "authTransactionManager")
public class AuthDataSourceConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.auth.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties authDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.auth.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource authDataSource() {
        return authDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "authEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean authEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(authDataSource());
        // only need to scan auth model package here for entity of auth module
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test.multipledatasouce.auth.model" });
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager authTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("authEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean authEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(authEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
```

This is my common data source config file for all other modules without authentication module

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
//here i am able to exclude auth repo and capture all other modules with help of excludeFilters
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.test.multipledatasouce.*", excludeFilters = {
        @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com.test.multipledatasouce.auth.*") }, entityManagerFactoryRef = "commonEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "commonTransactionManager")
public class CommonDataSourceConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.common.datasource")
    public DataSourceProperties commonDataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("app.common.datasource.configuration")
    public DataSource commonDataSource() {
        return commonDataSourceProperties().initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "commonEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean commonEntityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(commonDataSource());
        

> // only need to scan all other module except auth model package here
> // not able to exclude auth module        
> em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.test.multipledatasouce.*" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager commonTransactionManager(
            final @Qualifier("commonEntityManagerFactory") LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean commonEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(commonEntityManagerFactory.getObject());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your problem you are trying to have 2 packages, of which 1 should be authenticated. There are multiple ways to do it.

Option 1 : (Most simple and recommended)
Create two springboot application. One of each. Springboot provides options to micro-service based architecture, with two applications, ideally you are planning for

1. Segregation of concern (authentication required vs not required)
2. Have simple and specific services

Combining the two into one, will simply complicate and increase maintenance overheads. Thus recommended.

Option 2:
@Springbootapplication, has an inbuilt @ComponentScan. What ever falls in the same package structure will automatically get scanned. You can create 2 beans in your main class. One for authenticated (with component scan) and one without it. Split your code into two packages accordingly. All the common code can go into util or helper packages.